# How to integrate and run existing ReactJS Application in Electron

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, electron, chromium

For instance, I have an ReactJS application: https://iaya-664f3.firebaseapp.com/
You can see in the HTML source the `bundle.js` file.

I have tried to run this application as desktop application using Electron, which should launch this web application in chromium window but it is not working.

### Following is my main React application file `app.js` sitting in root directory. However compiled files `bundle.js` and `index.html` are in `./public/`directory.

### `./app.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const store = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore)(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(  <Provider store={store}>
                    <Router history={browserHistory}  routes={routes} />  
                </Provider> , 

                document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

### `./index.js`

In this file I'm embedding my application to Electron to run in chromium.

```
var app = require("./app");
var BrowserWindow = require("browser-window");

// on electron has started up , booted up, everything loaded (Chromium ,goen, live)
app.on("ready", function(){
    var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width:800,
        height:600
    });
    mainWindow.loadUrl("file://" + __dirname+ "/public/index.html");
});
```

But this give some error on `import React from 'React'` line in my `./app.js`.

So I assume that, I should only give `./public/index.html` file to load which includes the compiled `bundle.js`. But I wonder, how that will work as the line `app.on("ready", function(){` expect an `app`.

Moreover I have also tried following way in **`./index.js`** but it gives some other error.

```
const electron = require('electron');

// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app;

// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    /*mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));*/
    mainWindow.loadURL("file://" + __dirname+ "/public/index.html");

    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', function () {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the thing is very simple. Electron acts just like a desktop chromium wrapper, that displays your any (any) type of web page inside desktop chromium.

So for example, we want to display http://www.google.com then you simply pass this URL to your `loadURL()` function.

Here is the working copy of code (asked in the question):

```
const electron = require('electron');
  // Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app;
  // Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

app.on('ready', function(){
    var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

    mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:8080/");  // option1: (loading a local app running on a local server)

    //mainWindow.loadURL("https://iaya-664f3.firebaseapp.com");  // option2: (loading external hosted app)

    // loading developer tool for debugging
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
});
```

I hope this will clarify the confusion for many people, who are new to `Electron`. So the final words are that `Electron` only loads existing and running web application. It does not compile, does not act as a server. It is just a box in which you can put anything and give it a desktop sort of look e.g. menues, desktop notification, local file system access, etc.